# How to join two tables on some condition

Tags: sql, join

`Table1` is 6000 rows of numbers in `colA` and W or A in `colB`, and this works nicely

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM Table1
WHERE (colA = 1 AND colB = "A");
```

when I try and separate the tables (I know I should be using a JOIN - but...)
so that I have
Table1
6000 rows of numbers in colA
Table2
6000 rows of W or A in colB

this works I think (but runs out of memory)

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE (Table1.colA = 1 AND Table2.colB = "A");
```

how would i join the tables to make this work ? I seem to find JOIN hard to grasp even though i have read quite a bit on this subject

any help much appreciated

Comment: Add a bit of sample data. Is Table2 really just 3000 `A` values and 3000 `B` values? What's the desired result of your query?

Comment: Are you trying to determine how many "A" and "W" values are in the table?

Comment: You're going to need another column on each table to associate them.

Comment: As tuespetre states you are going to need another column in each of the tables, the reason for this is that otherwise you are destroying information. `{(1000,W);(2000,A)}` has more information than `{1000;2000} {W;A}`.  This because the tables in a database is not actually a list, it's a set and so order is arbitrary.  This means that when you join the columns back together you will need something to relate them.  So the question boils down to; why do you want to split the columns into two tables?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help you.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
AS SELECT * FROM table_master
WHERE colB = 'A'

SELECT count(*) FROM Table1 WHERE (colA = 1 AND colB = 'A');

CREATE TABLE Table2
AS SELECT * FROM Table_Master
WHERE colB = 'W'

SELECT count(*) FROM Table2 WHERE (colA = 1 AND colB = 'W');
```

I guess , you require a combined data from these two tables (Table1 and Table2).
So we can use union to join the tables.

```
Select * From
(
    SELECT * FROM Table1
    union all
    SELECT * FROM Table2
)
WHERE (Table1.colA = 1 AND Table2.colB = 'A');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from table1
where cola = 1
union all
select * from table2
where colb = 'A'
```

If you want to avoid repetition, you'll have to use union instead of union all

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` is used to attach tables side-by-side (lining up rows based on some condition).

`UNION` is used to attach two tables top to bottom (showing the results from each table as separate rows)

`UNION ALL` works the same as `UNION` except duplicate records between the two tables are removed from the result.

While it's unclear what your desired result is, it sounds more like you want a `UNION`:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM Table1
WHERE (colA = 1 AND colB = "A");

UNION ALL

SELECT count(*) 
FROM Table2
WHERE (colA = 1 AND (colB = "A" OR colB = "W"));
```

Answer (score 0):

My epiphany when reading about JOIN came when someone exaplained to me the a JOIN is a cartesian products of the tables. In your example, in case 1 you have something like this:

```
Table1
colA  |colB
1     |W
2     |W
1     |A
2     |A
```

Selecting from this table is easy and you managed to do it ok.
In the case of two tables:

```
Table1      Table2
colA        colB
1           W
2           W
1           A
2           A
```

The result of the JOIN is a product of all the rows, like this:

```
Table1 JOIN Table2
colA        colB
1           W
1           W
1           A
1           A
2           W
2           W
2           A
2           A
1           W
1           W
1           A
1           A
2           W
2           W
2           A
2           A
```

yes, 16 rows (4x4) this is why in a JOIN you generally tend to have a `ON...` clause so that the JOIN is restricted to matching rows.

Armed with this knowledge, if you want to get the same result from your `SELECT COUNT(*)` query in both cases, you will need to restrict the JOIN. Usually a key-foreign key relationship is all you need.